# Two BSD servers using CARP + LAGG both servers are MASTER, cant demote secondary to STANDBY

Tags: freebsd

Two BSD servers with Common Address Redundancy Protocol (CARP) configured to run over an interface using link aggregation (LAGG). Both servers are CARP MASTERs and there seems to be nothing I can do to demote one of them to STANDBY. I can manually force the second server to STANDBY but it reverts to MASTER within a few seconds. I used 'tcpdump' and saw lots of CARP keepalives from BOTH servers were arriving at BOTH servers.

Has anybody got this to work? What is the trick?

This is a cross posting from stackoverflow - perhaps this is the better site for this question.

**Server 1 (should be master)**

```
   $ ifconfig lagg0
   lagg0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
           options=e507bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM, \
                 TSO4,TSO6,LRO,VLAN_HWFILTER,VLAN_HWTSO,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
           ether 00:25:90:e9:d5:74
           inet 111.222.333.83 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 104.225.9.95
           inet 111.222.333.84 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 104.225.9.84 vhid 1
           inet 111.222.333.85 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 104.225.9.85 vhid 3
           inet 101.24.0.83 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 10.242.0.83
           inet6 fe80::225:90ff:fee9:d574%lagg0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
           inet6 2607:fc50:3000:4::83 prefixlen 64
           inet6 2607:fc50:3000:4::84 prefixlen 64 vhid 2
           inet6 2607:fc50:3000:4::85 prefixlen 64 vhid 4
           laggproto lacp lagghash l2,l3,l4
           laggport: igb0 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
           laggport: igb1 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
           groups: lagg
           carp: MASTER vhid 1 advbase 1 advskew 100
           carp: MASTER vhid 3 advbase 1 advskew 0
           carp: MASTER vhid 2 advbase 1 advskew 100
           carp: MASTER vhid 4 advbase 1 advskew 0
           media: Ethernet autoselect
           status: active
           nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>

   $ sysctl -a | egrep 'lagg|carp'
          net.inet.carp.ifdown_demotion_factor: 240
          net.inet.carp.senderr_demotion_factor: 240
          net.inet.carp.demotion: 0
          net.inet.carp.log: 1
          net.inet.carp.preempt: 1
          net.inet.carp.dscp: 56
          net.inet.carp.allow: 1
          net.link.lagg.lacp.default_strict_mode: 1
          net.link.lagg.lacp.debug: 0
          net.link.lagg.default_flowid_shift: 16
          net.link.lagg.default_use_flowid: 0
          net.link.lagg.failover_rx_all: 0
```

**Server 2 (should be standby)**

```
   lagg0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
           options=e527bb<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,JUMBO_MTU,VLAN_HWCSUM,TSO4, \
                 TSO6,LRO,WOL_MAGIC,VLAN_HWFILTER,VLAN_HWTSO,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
           ether 78:45:c4:fa:d2:99
           inet 111.222.333.82 netmask 0xfffffff0 broadcast 104.225.9.95
           inet 111.222.333.84 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 104.225.9.84 vhid 1
           inet 111.222.333.85 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 104.225.9.85 vhid 3
           inet 101.24.0.82 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 10.242.0.82
           inet6 fe80::7a45:c4ff:fefa:d299%lagg0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
           inet6 2607:fc50:3000:4::82 prefixlen 64
           inet6 2607:fc50:3000:4::84 prefixlen 64 vhid 2
           inet6 2607:fc50:3000:4::85 prefixlen 64 vhid 4
           laggproto lacp lagghash l2,l3,l4
           laggport: igb0 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
           laggport: igb1 flags=1c<ACTIVE,COLLECTING,DISTRIBUTING>
           groups: lagg
           carp: MASTER vhid 1 advbase 1 advskew 200
           carp: MASTER vhid 3 advbase 1 advskew 200
           carp: MASTER vhid 2 advbase 1 advskew 100
           carp: MASTER vhid 4 advbase 1 advskew 0
           media: Ethernet autoselect
           status: active
           nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>

   sysctl -a | egrep 'lagg|carp'
           <6>[26809290] carp: 3@lagg0: MASTER -> BACKUP (user requested via ifconfig)
           <6>[26809290] lagg0: deletion failed: 3
           <6>[26809294] carp: 3@lagg0: BACKUP -> MASTER (master timed out)
           <6>[26809296] carp: 1@lagg0: MASTER -> BACKUP (user requested via ifconfig)
           <6>[26809296] lagg0: deletion failed: 3
           <6>[26809300] carp: 1@lagg0: BACKUP -> MASTER (master timed out)
           net.inet.carp.ifdown_demotion_factor: 240
           net.inet.carp.senderr_demotion_factor: 240
           net.inet.carp.demotion: 0
           net.inet.carp.log: 1
           net.inet.carp.preempt: 1
           net.inet.carp.dscp: 56
           net.inet.carp.allow: 1
           net.link.lagg.lacp.default_strict_mode: 1
           net.link.lagg.lacp.debug: 0
           net.link.lagg.default_flowid_shift: 16
           net.link.lagg.default_use_flowid: 0
           net.link.lagg.failover_rx_all: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, check firewall rules.
CARP protocol must be enabled in this network(between these hosts).

Comment: Yep, Spot on. While investigating something else I had discovered the CARP keep-alives were being blocked.